# Alarm Manager Cancel Not Working Android

Tags: android

I have created an alarm manager for appointment reminder and its working fine. But when i want to cancel the alarm it still fire on time. Alarm Cancel is not working. Below is the code to set and cancel alarm. Thanks

### Code to set alarm manager

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);    
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.APPOINTMENT_REMINDER_NOTIFICATION");
notificationIntent.putExtra("APPOINTMENT_TIME", date);
notificationIntent.putExtra("APPOINTMENT_ID", appointment_id);
notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");    
PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);    
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, time_remaining);
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
```

### Cancel Alarm

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.APPOINTMENT_REMINDER_NOTIFICATION");
//PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).cancel();
//Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
//alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getService(context, 100, intent, 0));    
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(pIntent);
pIntent.cancel();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First thing to remember while working with `alammanager` is - 
**You must have to use same `context` while creating as well as cancelling the alarms.**

> This includes their action, data, type, class, and categories are the same. This
>   does not compare any extra data included in the intents.

In this case you can use `getApplicationContext()` to make things easy. So the code below should work -

*Setting an alarm -*

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.APPOINTMENT_REMINDER_NOTIFICATION");
notificationIntent.putExtra("APPOINTMENT_TIME", date);
notificationIntent.putExtra("APPOINTMENT_ID", appointment_id);
notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, time_remaining);
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
```

*Cancelling an alarm -*

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(pIntent);
```

Comment: i have checked with Application class context. still its not working

Comment: Where did you read you must use the same context? Two alarms are the same if they share the same `Intent` as described in docs. Checkout the `filterEquals` on `Intent` it compares: `mAction`, `mData`. `mType`, `mPackage`, `mComponent` and `mCategories`.

Answer (score 1):

in the brodcast reciver class make new Intent with the action name. 
dont pass the intent you got on onRecive method

for me it worked

Answer (score 0):

**You need to provide the same exact intent**

```
private void resetIntentWithAlarm(int time){


    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DownloadService.class);
    intentAlarm.putExtra(Your Key, Your stuff to pass here);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(),
            YOUR_ID,
            intentAlarm,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );

if (time != 0) {

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (60L * 1000L * time), (60L * 1000L * time), pendingIntent);
    Log.i(TAG, "Alarm setted on for " + time + " mins.");
}
// if TIME == Zero, cancel alaram
else {

    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    Log.i(TAG, "Alarm CANCELED. Time = " + time);
}
```